# Does stimulating lymph flow speed up adaptive immune response?

Tags: immune-system, lymph-nodes

TL;DR it seems that one mayor factor slowing down the adaptive immune response is the slowness with which Dendritic cells travel through the lymphatic system. Is it effective for to purposefully accelerate the flow in the lymphatic system when one knows they have been infected by some virus that will require immediate action from the immune system?

I have been reading the book Immune by Philipp Dettmer, as an introduction to how the immune system functions. Here, I learned that Dendritic cells take a full day to go from the site of an infection to the lymph nodes, where they can recruit the adaptive immune cells and begin the adaptive immune response.

Additionally, I also learned that the speed of the response is extremely important for a successful defence, especially in case of viral infections. The slow immune response makes sense evolutionary as defending against every small infection with an immediate and large scale mobilization of the adaptive immune system is neither efficient nor healthy.

However, as an intelligent human being, I am generally aware of when I have been exposed to germs and also whether the infection that got into me is a very dangerous kind or not. As such, I was wondering if it would be possible for me to consciously attempt to speed up the flow in the lymphatic system so that the Dendritic cells can get to a lymph node quicker. A search on the internet found many suggestions for how I could accelerate the flow of lymph, such as through physical exercise (trampoline jumping seems to be especially recommended), deep breathing, and drinking sufficiently many fluids. However, these suggestions tend to be intended for people whose lymphatic system is generally performing poorly.

In light of this background, my question is:
is it effective for a person with a generally well-functioning lymphatic system to purposefully accelerate the flow in the lymphatic system when they know they have been infected by some virus that will require immediate action from their immune system?

UPDATE: In light of the comments I have done some additional literature search and found that a portion of the Dendritic cells journey is spent not inside the lymph flow, but on the way to the lymph flow, through the peripheral tissue [1]. I found that this process is affected both by the Circadian rhythm [2] and by the presence of Myosin II [1]. In the comments to the question, it was pointed out that in fact the portion of the journey that is actually inside the lymph flow is insignificant but I was unable to find quantitative results on this. Regardless, it does seem to be the case that the 24 hours for a Dendritic cell to get to a Lymph node is affected by much more than just the speed of the flow of the Lymphatic system.

[1]: Myosin II Activity Is Selectively Needed for Migration in Highly Confined Microenvironments in Mature Dendritic Cells, Lucie Barbier et al.
[2]: Lymphocyte Circadian Clocks Control Lymph Node Trafficking and Adaptive Immune Responses, David Drudz et al.

Comment: "I am generally aware of when I have been exposed to germs and also whether the infection that got into me is a very dangerous kind or not" - you really, truly, are not.

Comment: @KateGregory you're right, I should rephrase, "there are times when I know I have been exposed to potentially dangerous germs" eg when I know I have spent a day in a small, badly ventilated room with a person who the day after tested positive for COVID, and who was already coughing much during the meeting; would the statement be correct then?

Comment: better, yes @poseidaan

Comment: I will be surprised to learn that anyone has studied this question specifically in humans. Have you done a search of the literature to find out? How about animal studies? Have you looked for those?

Comment: 8 Liters of lymph are produced per day. That's more volume than the amount of blood in circulation (about 5 liters) and it doesn't sit around in your tissues, or we would all have edema in our extremities, which is not the case. If you can find out how quickly lymph is returned to the blood, you might realize that the "delay" that you can make up for by speeding up its circulation is much less than you think. (i.e. that lymph moves quickly.)